# Missing the Rails 2.2.2 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans-6.9

I'm relatively new to linux but I'm trying to get a dev environment set up on Ubuntu 11.10. I have ruby 1.8 and rails 2.2.2 installed but netbeans seems to be telling me otherwise with the following error.

```
Missing the Rails 2.2.2 gem. Please gem install -v=2.2.2 rails, update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.
```

gem list

```
actionmailer (2.2.2)
actionpack (2.2.2)
activerecord (2.2.2)
activeresource (2.2.2)
activesupport (2.2.2)
rack (1.0.1)
rails (2.2.2)
rake (0.9.2.2)
```

gem list -d rails

```
rails (2.2.2)
Author: David Heinemeier Hansson
Rubyforge: http://rubyforge.org/projects/rails
Homepage: http://www.rubyonrails.org
Installed at: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

Web-application framework with template engine, control-flow layer,
and ORM.
```

I've seen similar questions but I still haven't been able to get any different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be pointing to your wrong gem home

```
whereis gem
```

http://wiki.netbeans.org/RubyGems

Comment: Thanks for the link. I got my problems solved. Netbeans was pointing at the wrong ruby platform. Solved it by going to Tools > Ruby Gems

Comment: Would also prob look at another IDE. Netbeans dropped support for Ruby.   I have moved to Rubymine